# How to run a lot of one-time tasks individually or in batches with some interval between each other?

Tags: elixir

I want to run 500 tasks either

- a) in a series of 8-10 ones with a  detay between **each batch**; or
- b) one by one but with a delay between **each task**

Each series (a) or an individual task (b) shouldn't `await(..)` for the result of the previous series (a) or task (b). Namely, it should simply run -- after a delay.

Optionally, a delay may be a **little** random each time: 2 seconds, then 4 seconds, then 3 seconds, then 1 second....

How to do this? In a simple manner. Preferably, with no additional dependencies other than OTP itself.

I could use `:timer.sleep(my_rand_delay)` but this will block the main thread, huh?

Answer (score 1):

Simple default elixir is all you need.

Here you go!

```
tasks =
    for n <- 0..7, into: [] do
        :timer.sleep(Enum.random(1000..3000))
        Task.async(fn ->
            :timer.sleep(Enum.random(1000..3000))
            IO.inspect(n, label: "Running task")
        end)
    end

IO.inspect("Waiting for tasks to run")
Task.await_many(tasks)
IO.inspect("All tasks finished")
```